# VB-NET Como dar um novo local á um controle?, com um valor de variável

Tags: vb.net

Eaê Pessoal.

Tenho esse código para definir um New Point para uma PictureBox, mas na hora de rodar não funciona,e é até obvio porquê não, vão saber no código abaixo...

```
Dim VarPbx As String = "PictureBox" & "2" 
Dim pbx As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls.Find(VarPbx, True).FirstOrDefault, PictureBox)    
Dim ValorLocation As String = "324, 212"

pbx.Location = New Point(ValorLocation)
```

Descobriram? Sou leigo mesmo ´-´

Já tentei outros tipo de variáveis para(ValorLocation) mas ele da error expected em alguns dos números, o certo é o valor ser Decimal né? Agradeço por você abrir esse post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É simples: você está passando uma String (cadeia de caracteres) como argumento para construir um novo `Point`, e a construção correta é `(int, int)`.

Veja o exemplo:

```
Dim VarPbx As String = "PictureBox" & "2"

Dim pbx As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls.Find(VarPbx, True).FirstOrDefault, PictureBox)

Dim ValorLocationX As Integer = 324
Dim ValorLocationY As Integer = 212

pbx.Location = New Point(ValorLocationX, ValorLocationY)
```

---

Além disso, você não precisa disso para chamar um membro pelo nome dele:

```
Dim VarPbx As String = "PictureBox" & "2"

Dim pbx As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls.Find(VarPbx, True).FirstOrDefault, PictureBox)
```

Você pode simplificar com:

```
Dim VarPbx As PictureBox = Me.PictureBox2
```

Dê uma lida sobre [instruções](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/sub-statement), [parâmetros](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments) e [tipos de dados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/data-type-summary). =)

Comment: Obrigado, é que nessa parte: Dim VarPbx As String = "PictureBox" & "2" esse valor dois é na vdd aqui uma variável que vai mudar pra mudar outras PictureBox´s